# What does the eigenspace E(1, A) mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

What does this notation stand for? The eigenspace $E(1, A)$ where $A$ is a $n \times n$ matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take this to mean the space of eigenvectors of A which have an eigenvalue of 1 (including the zero vector). These eigenvectors form a vector space because the property of being an eigenvector with a given eigenvalue is preserved by scalar multiplication and by vector addition. The eigenspace of eigenvectors of A with an eigenvalue $\lambda$ is usuallly written as $E_\lambda(A)$, but $E(\lambda, A)$ works too.